# Gotham episode where the term 'black market' was taken literally

Tags: dc, batman, episode-identification, gotham

In this particular episode, there was a 'Black Market' where types of contraband were sorted in different aisles with signs marking where each type of illegal item was, in a similar manner to a real-life supermarket. Criminals went down each aisle pushing actual shopping carts.

Comment: S1E8 'The Mask'? They go see a black market doctor.

Comment: I opened this question expecting all of the illegal goods to be colored black

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sounds like you're referring to '[The Merc](https://gotham.fandom.com/wiki/The_Merc),' which appeared in *Gotham* **S02E05**, "[Rise of the Villains: Scarification](https://gotham.fandom.com/wiki/Rise_of_the_Villains:_Scarification)."

From a [recap of the episode](https://www.superherohype.com/features/356179-gotham-episode-2-05-recap-and-preview-for-next-week):

> The youngest Pike heads to the Merc, which is like the CostCo of heavy artillery. Literally – there are friendly “blue light special” announcements, and shopping carts for the big spenders.